# AngularJS dynamic scope variables

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a scope variable `jsonData` as below:

```
$scope.jsonData={id:'1234',abcd:{array:[{a:'data',b:'bdata',c:'cdata'},{a2:'a2data',b2:'b2data',c2:'c2data'}]},efg:{test:'testdata'}}
```

in my HTML I have a function `calladd('jsonData.abcd.array')` with a string

in my js file I want to add an JSON object to arrayinside the abcd JSON object

```
$scope.add(data) {
    $scope[data].push({a3:'a3data',b3:'b3data',c3:'c3data'});
}
```

but I am unable to push data into array.

Comment: You can't go more than 1 level deep with a string like that - you'll need to parse it out and perform the actual logic.

Comment: `$scope` is an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to get ID, you can do

```
var id = $scope.jsonData.id;
//id = "1234"
```

You can use the same logic to add or get values

Answer (score 0):

Calling `myobject['prop1.prop2.whatever']` just doesn't work.

What you need is a recursive parser like :

```
$scope.add = function(data, scope){
    scope = (typeof scope === "undefined") ? $scope : scope;
    var datas = data.split('.');
    if(datas.length == 1){
        scope[datas[0]].push({
            a3: 'a3data',
            b3: 'b3data',
            c3: 'c3data'
        });
    }else{
        var first = datas.splice(0,1);
        $scope.add(datas.join('.'), scope[first]);
    }
};
```

[And the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/floo51/n0bn0k9o/2/)